# Firefox issue in webdriver

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

Unable to connect to host `127.0.0.1` using port `7055` after `45000 ms`

with FF version `45.0` and selenium standalone jar `2.51/2.52/2.53`.

I've tried a different version with no success. Is anyone having similar issues?

Comment: Is thr no1 here who knows about this issue.Can we have an solution to this plz??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=7055+after+45000